# Add content types programmatically into SPList takes too long

Tags: 2010, content-type, splist, content-type-hub

I've dozens of CTypes to add to an SPList programmatically (cause content types are provided by CTH) and each `oSPList.ContentTypes.Add()` takes almost 1sec. Is there any other approach ou code optimization for this 'issue'?

using List Definition is not the way to go, [cause](http://charliedigital.com/2011/02/18/most-annoying-thing-about-sharepoint-2010/) is required to add all the fields into the schema, and the idea is to get all of that info directly from the provided CT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, by [Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc)

Comment: do you mean that you introduced some parallelism in your code ?

Comment: yes. I call the method for the CT adding, asynchronously, after the creation of the splist.